# Using QueryDSL with MongoDB - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven, spring-data, querydsl

I'm trying to integrate QueryDSL with MongoDB (provided by Spring Data) I'm also using JPA repository, so I separated packages in model module and repository module. Spring Data dependencies are from Spring Data Realease Train version `Hopper-SR1`. Query DSL version `3.7.2`.

```
        <!-- Spring Data -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Query DSL-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

My plugin confuguration

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>

                <!-- JPA Query DSL -->
                <execution>
                    <id>jpa</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <!-- Mongo Query DSL -->
                <execution>
                    <id>mongo</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor
                        </processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I'm building my model module by `mvn clean install` and I'm getting error like below. I think that is something wrong with MongoDB processor in plugin, because if I use only JPA execution build passes.

```
[ERROR] execute error
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/querydsl/apt/AbstractQuerydslProcessor
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at com.mysema.maven.apt.AbstractProcessorMojo.execute(AbstractProcessorMojo.java:346)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/querydsl/apt/AbstractQuerydslProcessor
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:553)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/querydsl/apt/AbstractQuerydslProcessor
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$NameProcessIterator.hasNext(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:409)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$DiscoveredProcessors$ProcessorStateIterator.hasNext(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:609)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.atLeastOneProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:447)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.initProcessAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1050)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:852)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.querydsl.apt.AbstractQuerydslProcessor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 24 more
```

Just for sure, this dependencies I have in my parent `pom.xml`

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-bom.version}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As indicated in the [GA release announcement](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/07/spring-data-release-train-hopper-goes-ga-and-sr1) and [release train wiki](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Hopper), Spring Data Hopper upgrades to Querydsl 4. Thus, you also need to upgrade your application to it.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with QueryDsl / **Spring Boot 2.1.3**.

Simply changed: From:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.6</version>
</dependency>
```

To:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And relevant imports and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `querydsl` maven groupId by **com.querydsl** and use a version greater than 4.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the latest version of `spring-data-mongodb`. I had the same problem but resolved it with the `1.8.4-RELEASE` version.